# What regex can I use to match and replace full stops in multiple filenames?

Tags: regex

I am looking to replace full stops in a filename however I need to remove some and replace others.

The file names are structured like so:

**A.A** M12345678 SOMEWORD **20.08.2019**.pdf

**A.A** M12345678 SOMEWORD1 SOMEWORD2 **20.08.2019**.pdf

I want the format to be the following:

**AA** M12345678 SOMEWORD **20-08-2019**.pdf

**AA** M12345678 SOMEWORD1 SOMEWORD2 **20-08-2019**.pdf

So the first full stop should be removed but the full stop encountered in the date should be a hyphen (-).

I have been using command prompt but I am running into some issues as I am fairly new to regular expressions.

I have tried approaching the problem one step at a time namely by just focusing on replacing the date format.

I've tested my regex using https://regexr.com/ and it matches correctly.

[0-9]\K[.]

My understanding of the code above should match the full stops in the date.

However when I run the following command:

ren *[0-9]\K[.].pdf -

It fails to find the file.

#### Expected Result

**AA** M12345678 SOMEWORD **20-08-2019**.pdf

#### Actual Result

The expression I use just returns this error when I use the REN command.

"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: In this pattern `[0-9]\K[.].pdf` you should omit the dot before `.pdf` and leave only `[.]` to match a literal dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you could do this in the command-line with `sed` as follows. Run the following command:

`sed -i "s/(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\.(\d\d\d\d)/\1-\2-\3 ; s/^(.)\.(.*)/\1\2/" <YOUR_FILE>`

The `-i` flag is for modification in place. Here, I'm running two separate search-and-replace functions on each line; the first is to match to a date, and then format it accordingly, and the second is to match your `A.A` metadata and format it accordigly.

More about [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) here.

Comment: Yep, happy to help! Make sure you read up on capture groups, though; there's some insanely useful stuff in there!

Comment: Yeah I will definitely be reading up on this, regex is something I really am struggling to grasp so every little helps!